How is grammar used for recognizers?
I'm hoping to further understand how grammars are used in building recognizers for languages. Specifically, I know that a grammar defines the syntax of a language, but I'm confused about how this applies to recognizers.

How does a recognizer use grammar to determine whether a string belongs to a language?
Is there a standard process or algorithm that recognizers follow when working with grammars?

Also are there differences in how various types of grammars (like regular or context-free grammars) are used for building recognizers?
Any answers that can be provided to these questions would be appreciated.
Thank you.

"are there differences in how various types of grammars (like regular or context-free grammars) are used for building recognizers?" Definitely yes, and that makes the first part of this question very broad. Are you asking how to translate from a formal grammar into a finite state machine acceptor for the language defined by that grammar? If so, probably you need to narrow it down to a specific kind of language. Are you thinking of practical systems? Note also that [cs.se] will have questions about the formal side (they are ok here too, just noting the answer you want may already be there).

By "recognizer" do you mean parser? That may help you search. There are different kinds of parsing algorithms (LL and LR, which are divided into LL(1), LL(k), etc. and SLR, LALR, etc.), and algorithms that take a grammar in BNF or other form and generate said kinds of parser from it.

Take a step back. Suppose you were given a grammar. Here's one: "EXP is either a base 10 integer, or EXP * EXP, or ( EXP )".  Now suppose I gave you a string "1 * (2 * "  How would YOU, a person, determine that the string is not a member of the language defined by the grammar for the EXP language?  Somehow you did that; what steps did you take?  By doing toy examples "by hand" you'll get insights into how to write a program that automates your thought process.

Typically, a grammar is consumed by a parser generator (like ANTLR or YACC) in the category of compiler-compilers, not by a parser or recognizer itself.  The parser generator constructs a parser by reading a grammar.  That parser can then recognize the language described by the grammar.  The parser is constructed by the parser generator to incorporate all the rules (productions/recognitions) that were in the grammar.  Those rules are stored in tables and code in the generated parser program.

Oh yeah, sorry. I did mean parser. Thank you all so much for the explanations, though. They really help!
